# IOS App Rejection on IPV6

Tags: ios, cordova, ipv6, inappbrowser, phonegap

I recently uploaded an app on Apple store and they rejected by giving us following remarks:
**We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPhone and iPad running iOS 10.3.2 on Wi-Fi connected to an IPv6 network. To resolve this issue, please run your app on a device while connected to an IPv6 network (all apps must support IPv6) to identify any issues, then revise and resubmit your app for review.**
I used Phonegap, Cordova and ionic framework in my app. My app is opening some links in **inappbrowser cordova plugin**
Here is the code of controller.js

```
   var options = {
      location: 'no',
      clearcache: 'yes',
      toolbar: 'yes',
      transitionstyle: 'coververtical',
      closebuttoncaption: 'Back',
      toolbarposition: 'top',
      enableViewportScale: 'yes'
   };
  $cordovaInAppBrowser.open('URL of Website', '_blank', options)
```

Is there any plugin that overcome this problem?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you actually test your application on on IPv6-only network, as is required by Apple? Did you look at what Apple sent to see where it crashed?

Comment: Yes I tested app on ipv6 and I found that some of the links that I am opening using InAppBrowser are not opening.

Comment: Does the website you are linking to support ipv6?

Comment: No the websites that I am linking didn't support ipv6 but is there any way I can still open website in inAppBrowser?